# unable to retrieve selected value from select after cloning to a <form>

Tags: javascript, jquery

By cloning the fields such as  from 'fs-form', Im unable to retrieve the selected values whenever  the 'fs-form' is changed/updated

```
$("<form>").append($('fieldset[name=fs-form]').clone())
```

but if it was to be done to the dom, it can be seen for the selected value.

```
$("form").append($('fieldset[name=fs-form]').clone())
```

Comment: This `$("<form>")` is inappropriate css selector. Note that jQuery uses css selectors.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery selectors are based on CSS selectors. [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

So when you first do `$("<form>")` it searches for the best match with tag `<form>` but doesn't return the element object.

Whereas in the second case `$("form")` the CSS selector comes into the picture and it searches for the element `form` and returns a jQuery element object.

Here is an example of results you shall be getting:

```
console.log(jQuery('<div class="post-menu">'));
Result: n.fn.init [div.post-menu]

console.log(jQuery('.post-menu'));
Result: n.fn.init [div.post-menu, prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: ".post-menu"]
```

Notice the results with a selector and without a selector.
For accessing elements for manipulation like in your case append, always use standard CSS selectors.

Comment: thanks for  taking time for the explanation @Dhruvin.

"So when you first do $("<form>") it searches for the best match with tag <form> but doesn't return the element object."

So what does it return if finding n searching is allowed?

As for the form, $("<form>"), it returns a lot of wanted elements but not really the state of it ?

Comment: @lilsizzo `$("<form>")` will just return the search result and will just say that the `<form>` exists with length as 1 whereas if you do `$("form")` it will return all instances of forms with the elements.

"it returns a lot of wanted elements but not really the state of it ?" - that's correct

Comment: Ive tried goin deeper, but it seems that almost all <input> values/selected values are able to be retrieved but <select> ones are not able to

Answer (score 0):

**A.** `$("form").append($('fieldset[name=fs-form]').clone())`:

1. **Search for `form` tag.**
2. Search for all fieldset elements with `name=fs-form`.
3. Append Searched fieldset elements to the searched `form` element.
4. Makes a copy of `form` elements, including all fieldset elements.

**B.** `$("<form>").append($('fieldset[name=fs-form]').clone())`:

1. **Create a new `form` element.**
2. Search for all fieldset elements with `name=fs-form`. (Like the second stage of the above section)
3. Append Searched fieldset elements to the new created `form` elements.
4. Makes a copy of new created `form` elements, including all fieldset elements.

So, when you use `$('<form>')`, in fact you separate the `fielset` from the existing form and attach it to the new created form. So, in fact, the previous form does not contain any fieldset elements.

But when you use `$('form')`, the fieldset elements are taken from it and added to it again.

Please see the examples below to find out the difference between these two.

**Example A:**

```js
function copy() {
    var copy = $( 'form' ).append($( 'fieldset[name="fs-form"]' ) ).clone();
    copy.appendTo( 'body' )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <fieldset name="fs-form">
        Name: <input type="text"><br>
        Email: <input type="text">
    </fieldset>
</form>

<button type="button" onclick="copy()">Clone &dollar;( 'form' ) and append to body</button>
```

**Example B:**

```js
function copy() {
    var copy = $( '<form>' ).append($( 'fieldset[name="fs-form"]' ) ).clone();
    copy.appendTo( 'body' )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <fieldset name="fs-form">
        Name: <input type="text"><br>
        Email: <input type="text">
    </fieldset>
</form>

<button type="button" onclick="copy()">Clone &dollar;( '&lt;form&gt;' ) and append to body</button>
```

Comment: Hi Kavian,
"So, when you use $('<form>'), in fact you separate the fielset from the existing form and attach it to the new created form. So, in fact, the previous form does not contain any fieldset elements". 

So when we get the the fieldset from existing form, should the value/selected value be appended into <form> then? in my case, almost all <input> fields , their values or selected values are able to be retrieved/searched. But for <select> tag, i  couldnt

Comment: From [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/clone/#entry-longdesc): For performance reasons, the dynamic state of certain form elements (e.g., user data typed into textarea and user selections made to a select) is not copied to the cloned elements. When cloning input elements, the dynamic state of the element (e.g., user data typed into text inputs and user selections made to a checkbox) is retained in the cloned elements